# How can I maintain open ssh connection and use it from shell scripts?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Currently i invoke the following:

```
$ ssh me@host.com my_cmd
```

This is slow and not easy to automate safely.
I would like to establish ssh connection once and have some script that will forward my commands to host.com and print output.

Is that possible ?

Adding my machine to authorized_keys is not an option for me and it wouldn't solve slowness issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The feature is called `ControlMaster` which does multiplexing over one existing channel. It causes ssh to do all of the key exchanges and logging in only once; thus, the later commands will go through much faster. You activate it using these three lines in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host host.com
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%C
  # for openssh < 6.7 you need to use this one:
  # ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h-%p
  ControlPersist 5m
```

You can adjust it to your needs; one alternative is that you could open one master connection that stays open during your other commands; then you would not need `ControlPersist`.

There are many possibilities with this feature to tweak, but make sure you store your `ControlPath` socket in a safe place, not readable by other users, otherwise it could be misused.

More info can be found in the `ssh_config(5)` manual page.

Comment: percent_expand: unknown key %C

Comment: It looks like the `%C` substitution was added in `openssh-6.7` so it doesn't work in all openssh versions. If it doesn't work, you can always use `%r@%h-%p` as proposed in the other answer. I will update mine accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control of the machine to the point that you are automating tasks on it, then why is adding your key to authorized_keys not an option?

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/foo somehost@example.com
```

Then you don't have to enter a password every time you connect.

If the biggest problem is that connections take a long time to connect, you could reuse a single connection by adding `control master` to your ssh config. Leave that one connection running, an any subsequent connections will be nearly instantaneous.

```
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
ControlPersist 600
```

https://puppetlabs.com/blog/speed-up-ssh-by-reusing-connections

In the long run, if you are automating tasks, you are proabably better off using an automation framework that handles establishing the connection for you, like :

- [mcollective](https://puppetlabs.com/mcollective)
- [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home)
- [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/)

Comment: Server owner policy might  prevent use of authorized_keys