Pool SSH connections
I'd like to interactively initiate a good number of processes on a remote machine by SSH. However, this means I have to initiate a separate SSH connection to the remote machine for every new process. Is there a way I can pool (or multiplex?) SSH connections, so that when I want a new process, I just take an existing connection and start my process on it?

Look for the ControlMaster option and relayed ones, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218272/how-can-i-maintain-open-ssh-connection-and-use-it-from-shell-scripts

@ilkkachu isn't that a dup?

Note that you may need to increase the max multiplexed connections
MaxSessions from the default of 10 as mentioned
here.
Alternatively, depending on circumstances, look at using something like tmux or
terminator on the remote.
